# MySQL query using update or select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE client_service_details(
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client_details_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`service_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`list_index`  int(10)  NOT NULL default 0 ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB ;


+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
| id | client_details_id | service_id | list_index |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |               101 |          1 |          0 |
|  2 |               101 |          2 |          0 |
|  3 |               101 |          3 |          0 |
|  4 |               102 |          1 |          0 |
|  5 |               102 |          2 |          0 |
|  6 |               102 |          3 |          0 |
|  7 |               102 |          4 |          0 |
|  8 |               103 |          1 |          0 |
|  9 |               103 |          2 |          0 |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

WE want to update the column (list_index) based on the client_details_id, servce_id.
Or if we we get the select statement as give below the it is okay

The output should be as follows:

```
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
| id | client_details_id | service_id | list_index |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |               101 |          1 |          0 |
|  2 |               101 |          2 |          1 |
|  3 |               101 |          3 |          2 |
|  4 |               102 |          1 |          0 |
|  5 |               102 |          2 |          1 |
|  6 |               102 |          3 |          2 |
|  7 |               102 |          4 |          3 |
|  8 |               103 |          1 |          0 |
|  9 |               103 |          2 |          1 |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: i dont understand how exactly list_index should be updated

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE client_service_details
SET list_index = service_id -1
```

this should work

Comment: no. the service_id may be any number. it may not be the same series

Comment: So what is rule for updating it... what exactly are you looking for? If there is no rule, you will have to manually update it.

Comment: we need to group based on the client_id and server_id

Comment: UPDATE client_service_details SET list_index=<abc> WHERE client_id = <x> AND server_id = <y>, that is the only thing you can do if <abc> ends up being random